# Open source Android library for reading passport MRZ

Tags: android, open-source, library, ocr

So I want to recognize the MRZ portion of passport from a captured image,tried several OCR implementations for Android i.e Text Recognition API,MLKit etc. but none of them produces satisfactory results for recognizing MRZ.

Are there any open source libraries available for recognizing MRZ? or any OpenCV implementation for specifically recognizing the MRZ portion of passport.

[image]

Comment: I have done a lot of research recently and I have not been able to get any reliable open source SDK for MRZ. Almost all open source examples are either not up to date or are crappy and not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this example

https://github.com/mercuriete/android-mrz-reader

It's not working very perfect but could be useful in some cases.